# Width CommandBar (UWP)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

how can I change the width of CommandBar? I want the size of Desktop mode on Mobile mode.

Desktop mode:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSJGJ.png)

Mobile mode: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgJLE.png)

**Edit:**
This is my code, I don't use Flyout.

```
<CommandBar RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0">
  <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    <AppBarButton Name="shareButton" Label="Condividi" x:Uid="condividi" Click="shareButton_Click" Icon="ReShare" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" />
    <AppBarButton Name="contactButton" Icon="Contact" x:Uid="contatti" Label="Contatti" Click="contactButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" />
  </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not the commandbar. you need to check your xaml in the Flyout set the horizontal alignment to right of your items inside of the Flyout

Comment: I edit my question with the code. I don't use Flyout.

Answer (score 0):

The default overflow menu is styled to be distinct from the bar. You can adjust the styling by setting the [CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.commandbaroverflowpresenterstyle.aspx) property to a Style that targets the [CommandBarOverflowPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbaroverflowpresenter.aspx).  By default the overflow menu adapts its size and visuals based on the window width so that on small windows/screens it stretches to be the full width and only shows the border along the leading edge instead of around the entire menu.  You can override this by re-templating the menu.  In the example below I'm removing some of the visual states that alter the BorderThickness and I'm hard-coding the MaxWidth / MinWidth as well as the HorizontalAlignment (to prevent it from being stretched on smaller windows).

```
<CommandBar Margin="0">
    <CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                              MaxWidth="480"
                              MinWidth="196"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                           <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                          ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="0,7,0,7" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Name="shareButton" Label="Condividi" x:Uid="condividi" Icon="ReShare"/>
        <AppBarButton Name="contactButton" Icon="Contact" x:Uid="contatti" Label="Contatti"/>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```